# throws exception too many )'s in regex replace string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, exception

The following code throws exception stating `too many )'s in regex replace string` in c#

```
Regex r3 = new Regex(@"([(=_)!@#$%^&<>?/';:\~`]+)");   //characters
var match = r3.Match(input);

if (match.Success)  //characters
{
     string ch = match.Groups[1].Value;
     z = z + ch;
     textBox4.Text = z;
     string j = Regex.replace(input,ch , "");
     MessageBox.Show("String has become", j);
     input = j;
}
```

When the input contains a `(` or a `)` the mentioned exception is thrown

Comment: When you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
string j = Regex.replace(input,ch , "");
```

The `ch` contains the parentheses you are having problems with.

Your code can be simplified to reuse the `Regex`:

```
string j = r3.Replace(input, "");
```

You could also use a simple string replace here.

```
input.Replace(ch, "");
```

If you absolutely must use the static `Regex.Replace`, first escape all `Regex` special characters in the `ch` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to [(=_)!@#$%^&<>?/';:\~`]+ and it will work.